# How to change the text in checkout cart page in magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to change the text in checkout cart page in magento 2

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Below File

> app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{themename}/i18n/en_GB.csv

```
Country,Pays
State/Province,État/Province
"ZIP/Postal Code","Code postal"
```

**Note**: Clear cache (`php bin/magento cache:clean`) and check your changes.

Comment: its not working

Comment: @divyasekar your language code is what?

Comment: i need to change template file

Comment: language code is en_GB

Comment: i have not idea about template file but it is easy and good way to translate text i have update also which file you will to change